# Why multiCapabilities don't accept specs files from spec:[], why I need to divide specs in each instance in multiCapabilities

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, automated-tests, config

I am trying to distribute specs[file1, file2, file3] in multiCapabilities but then all the instances start running all the spec files, while I just want all instances to pic specs and test once.

When I pass specs inside multiCapabilities then it works fine but if I keep specs[] out of multiCapabilites and use shardTestFiles: true, then all browser instances run all the specs rather than all browser instances should rest all the specs once only.

```
exports.config = {
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxSessions: 5,
    specs: ['./Tests/spec1.js','./Tests/spec2.js', './Tests/spec3.js' ],
multiCapabilities: [
         {
          browserName : 'chrome',
          seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
         },
        {
          browserName : 'chrome',
          seleniumAddress: 'http://172.23.230.198:4444/wd/hub'         
        }
]
}
```

Expected Result:
2 instances of chrome browser should open and run all the 3 specs and share the result.

Actual Result:
2 instance of chrome browser open and run 3 specs in each browser repeatedly while 2 instances should run 3 specs once only.

Comment: This is definitely a weird instance. I just wonder if this optimization from a single capabilities is really going to save time. If this is the difference between a minute or two, I would suggest  leaving it as a single capability. If you are saving hours of CI, then going through your config, your `maxSessions` are the number of browser session that could be opened at the same time. `shardTestFiles` if set to true, should run the specs up to the `maxInstances`. My guess is you are adding in several configurations that do not play well together.

Comment: This is as Protractor designed.